# Alert System - 30 Days from a date - Help to get a code that verify each row of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, date, system, alert

Im workng on a program to manage payments that a company has to make to his suppliers, i can insert new payments into a database wich is show in a datagridview.

Each payment has some camps, one is the date of insertion of the payment and another with days you got to pay (date of insertion + 30, 60 or 90 days).

Row.7 is the date of insertion
Row.10 is the nunber of days (30,60 or 90).
I want to use these two camps and tell to the user how much time he have to pay and alert if 1 week or less to pay.

The only code i got until now is:

```
string dateInString = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString(); // Not sure about this

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInString);
        DateTime expiryDate = startDate.AddDays(30);
        if (DateTime.Now > expiryDate)
        {
            textBox3.Text = "Payment X has to be paid";
        }
```

The code i got before and works but this doesnt use any data from my database:

```
string dateInString = "10.05.2015"

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInString);
        DateTime expiryDate = startDate.AddDays(30);
        if (DateTime.Now > expiryDate)
        {
            textBox3.Text = "Payment X has to be paid";
        }
```

I know my code its still very basic, but im los on this one.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: So you've got some code... does that work? If not, in what way doesn't it work? If it does work, what more do you need? You haven't actually asked a question...

Comment: Row.7 is the date of insertion Row.10 is the nunber of days (30,60 or 90). I want to use these two camps and tell to the user how much time he have to pay and alert if 1 week or less to pay. Edit my main post also.

Comment: You've said you're "not sure" about one line - what's the problem? What's the actual data type of `row.Cells[7].Value`? Ideally it should be a `DateTime` that you can just cast to. Ditto `row.Cells[10].Value`...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, so I post you my code to check the date value and format the cell in different colours depending on the range of days till the actual date in datagridview. Hope you understand it.

```
private void dgv_tasks_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    if (this.dgv_tasks.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index == 3)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            DateTime dateValues = DateTime.Parse(dgv_tasks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;

            if ((dateValues - dateNow).TotalDays < 7)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }

            if (dateValues < dateNow)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help.  I edited the code, but i wanna get it to work when i press a button but i get a error when i put the code on the button, any ideia how to get it working in a button ?